# Sync google apps (gmail) contacts directory with Mac address book

Tags: gmail, contacts, google

We use Gmail (Google Apps for business) at my work.

I have set up my Mac (OS X 10.7.5) address book to sync the local address book with my gmail account, however this only syncs "My Contacts" but all my work contacts are in a group named "Directory" (a readable LDAP style group). I would like to sync my Mac address book with the Directory group but I can't find a way to do this.

I thought I had achieved a similar effect by dumping all the contacts from the directory into My Contacts, but it seems that only the email addresses are in My Contacts and the rest of the information is shown by being linked to the original Directory entry - therefore only email addresses are synced to the address book with no further information (e.g. addresses, telephone numbers...)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way to get all the contacts from the directory directly to your Mac. If you open the section in the Contacts Mac OS application, it will never list its entire content but only let you search.

However, there is an easy workaround:

1. Open the Contacts web interface https://www.google.com/contacts
2. On the sidebar, find the Directory option. The entire content will now appear.
3. Select all the entries.
4. Add these to a group, i.e. "Corp. Directory"

Now, all these contacts will be imported to "My Contacts" and will be synched to the Mac.

Comment: We've moved to Exchange since I wrote this question! So I can't verify whether this works in order to accept the answer. I could accept it on the face of it - is that bad StackExchange form?

Answer (score 1):

You can sync all your Gmail contacts to your Address Book on MAC.

Open Address Book Preferences and then open the Accounts tab.

Account Type must be CardDAV Account. Set your user name and password of your gmail account and finally type google.com to server address.

Comment: Thanks for that - it's good to have another protocol supported, but unfortunately it still doesn't address the problem that the "directory" group isn't synced - only "my contacts". Also, only the email addresses are synced - no other contact data. I guess Google isn't really ready to take on the Exchange/Outlook combination as I hoped it was.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very old topic, but it appears in my searches so I'd like to share a couple of possible Solutions... what I did in my Company..

First try was the creation  of an "address book " user,  like a service user, with its contacts periodically updated from the domain Directory: this user  was add in each smartphone or device in order to add in the Contact App all the Directory Users like personal contacts.
It worked great,but it needed manual job, and potentially a user could change one of these contacts.

Second try was this app: ShareDirectory Contacts ( https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/sharedirectory_contacts/43562572075?hl=it  ): it keeps each user contacts synchronized with the Domain Directory... I'm still testing it,but in these few weeks it seems to work well..

I hope these two suggestions may be useful for some of you...